# NullPointerException in SurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow(SurfaceView.java:207)

Tags: android

I'm getting this exception raised from SurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow. It looks like SurfaceView is trying to reference mParent, but it's null. Does anyone know why the parent wouldn't be set but onAttachedToWindow would be called?

I'm using the SurfaceView for a camera preview. I have a ViewGroup that is added/removed from the activity's root view. Inside the ViewGroup is the SurfaceView and a WebView.

Here is the code for the ViewGroup: http://pastebin.com/eSyZ3v3P and here is the code that show/hides the camera: http://pastebin.com/5iaEFCQr

Any help would be really appreciated.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.SurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow(SurfaceView.java:207)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11755)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1199)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

-- edit --

Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm not aware of the steps to reproduce the exception. The code works every time I run the app, but I'm getting these exceptions sent to my logger from a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. And the issue isn't consistent.

Comment: Which android API do u use ? 19 ?

Comment: I'm using API Level 15.

Comment: Hello kyle, have you got around it somehow? I found a way to reproduce it: Get an app with camera preview and camera-start button and camera-stop button. Now, if you get a mad user, and he presses :  Start Stop Start in less than 2 seconds, this exception gets thrown.

Comment: @rupinderjeet Interesting. I hadn't considered that. I've actually forgotten all about this issue since I did a re-write of my camera implementations. I ended up writing a state machine to ensure things didn't get called when the camera wasn't ready.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your bug is because you are using a stale View in this line:

```
setPreviewDisplay(this.surfaceView.getHolder())
```

In this line, when it crashes, surfaceView is no longer valid. You should use the SurfaceHolder returned in surfaceChanged/surfaceCreated.

This was the source of my bug also.

In general:

This error can occur when you are trying to attach a view (your preview) to a window that no longer exists.  For example, you have some long running code (opening the camera) and then you attach the view, and the phone has rotated (old context) or another app is showing (so its not valid to attach to the unseen view), or the lock screen is on, etc.

One way to avoid this situation is to make sure you have a visible window for your Activity before you try to attach your view. I wish I had more details to tell you how to do that.

One possible issue is that you are doing Camera.open(), which can take some time, especially on certain devices, before you call addView(), so maybe by the time you get around to addView(), the window is not available.  Consider doing Camera.open() on a background thread, and when all that is done, do addView().

I see that you have several threads running on the UI thread. You want to make sure those are all done before you do the addView.

Comment: This seems most likely the issue. What is the best way to accommodate this race condition?

Comment: @Kyle  I think I found the source of your crash - let me know! See my updated answer.

Comment: @Lucy, was there anything else suspicious than this? I think doing `setPreviewDisplay()` immediately after `camera.open()` causes this too. Did you happen to find more information?

Comment: @rupinderjeet I don't have any additional information. Like I said, Consider doing Camera.open() on a background thread, and when all that is done, do your thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what causes it but I could think of only 1 work around:

```
    this.surfaceView = new SurfaceView(customContext) {
        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see android.view.SurfaceView#onAttachedToWindow()
         */
        @Override
        protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
            if(this.getParent() != null)
                super.onAttachedToWindow();
        }
    };
```

Can't test it though to see if it will create more issues or just fix this one.

I know it's hackish but I thought it wouldn't hurt to write it.

Try it at your own risk!

Comment: `this.getParent()` is nothing.

Comment: WHat do you mean ?

Comment: there is no `getParent()` method for `this`. In this case, your `this` is a `SurfaceView`. And, Mr.SurfaceView does not provide any `getParent()` method.

Comment: I honestly don't remember this is from 2014, maybe I meant `CurrentClass.this.getParent()` but I can't be sure now because I moved jobs and I don't do android anymore

Answer (score 1):

Inside the constructor of the class [CameraPluginView](http://pastebin.com/PbdaJ4h4) , you pass **customContext**

```
           this.surfaceView = new SurfaceView(getContext());
```

Instead of the previous call, try this [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) :

```
         SurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

which is "called when inflating a view from XML"

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. I was trying to remove anything identifiable to the project and forgot to update those references from "context" to "customContext". I've made the updates in the code. Rest assured, the only things that have changed between the actual code and the code you see is just the names of objects.

Comment: I think you have to present also `SurfaceView` class file because exception happens inside `onAttachedToWindow`. This would help, in my opinion.

Comment: [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) is part of Android's SDK :)

Comment: I changed a little bit the answer now that is it's better to pass this   which means the `CameraPluginView` itself.

Comment: CameraPluginView is an indirect subclass of View. No where does it subclass Context. So putting the context for SurfaceView as "this" gives me an incompatibility error.

Comment: I mean something like : `view.getContext()` and you can access the current theme, resources, etc. If `this.getContext()` isn't possible then cast it to `view`

Comment: Isn't this.getContext() the exact same as the variable I was passing?

Comment: I think you are right : `getContext()` is the same with your custom context. So, I changed my answer and you should try another `SurfaceView` constructor with [AttributeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your **mParent** may be null because the assignView in **View.java** may be not called. Check this. The simple way to check what's wrong - create a sample project with `TextView` and check in debug step-by-step(make breakpoints in `assignView()` method and `onAttachedToWindow()`) and you will see what's the problem.

Comment: The problem is that it's not easily reproducible.