# Android - weird crash in SurfaceView

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, surfaceview, glsurfaceview, null-pointer

I am getting these weird exceptions in Firebase (I am assuming they are the same thing) but I haven't been able to debug this. It never happens to me even though I have the same device as one of the users who get it. Also I can't seem to find the method `requestTransparentRegion` in the source code of `GlSurfaceView` or `SurfaceView`.

Any help resolving this?

Android 9

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.view.ViewParent.requestTransparentRegion(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
android.view.SurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow (SurfaceView.java:236)
android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow (GLSurfaceView.java:610)
android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:18359)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:1773)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1471)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7211)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1004)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:816)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:751)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:990)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
```

Android 10

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void android.view.ViewParent.requestTransparentRegion(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
android.view.SurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow (SurfaceView.java:249)
android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.onAttachedToWindow (GLSurfaceView.java:611)
android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:20186)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:2085)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1778)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7894)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1041)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:864)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:798)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1026)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
```

My GlSurfaceView subclass

```
public class MyGlSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MyRenderer myRenderer;

    public MyGlSurfaceView(Context context){
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyGlSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet set){
        super(context, set);
        init(context);
    }

    void init(Context context){
        setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
        setZOrderOnTop(true);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
        getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        myRenderer = new MyRenderer(this);
        setRenderer(myRenderer);
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);

    }

}
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390225/nullpointerexception-in-surfaceview-onattachedtowindowsurfaceview-java207

Comment: Moreover, **requestTransparentRegion** is a method of ViewGroup class